# Custom Set of Steps in Slider

Tags: swift, xcode, slider, step

I have a @StateObject Slider. It is set to slide 1...5 step 1.
I need to have custom step [1,2,5,10,20] instead of step 1.

I have a setup where I have the slider work as an array index to my array of custom step. It is working. But It is jerky. Single slide registers slide value dozen times making my array to get picked up dozen times jerking the process. How can I have custom steps smooth.

I can adjust within the app but if Slider provides the exact number, logic of the app become much cleaner. Less translation, clear the logic.

```
Slider(value: $tSlider, in: 1...5, step: 1) 

// How can I make above like below
Slider(value: $tSlider, in: 1...5, step: [1,2,5,10,20]

// What I have currently
@Published var tSteps:[Int] = [1,2,5,10,20]
@Published var tSlider: Double = 1
var tScale: Int { return tlSteps[Int(tlSlider)-1] }
```

Comment: Consider adding tag of programming language you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Setting steps on Slider was a bad idea. Stepper was correct choice.

```
Stepper("Year Scale", onIncrement: {
    switch tVM.tlScale {
    case 1: self.tlScale = 2
    case 2: self.tlScale = 5
    case 5: self.tlScale = 10
    case 10: self.tlScale = 20
    default: self.tlScale = 20
    },
    onDecrement: {
    switch tVM.tlScale {
    case 20: self.tlScale = 10
    case 10: self.tlScale = 5
    case 5: self.tlScale = 2
    case 2: self.tlScale = 1
    default: self.tlScale = 1
    }
})
```

referred to : post here and Skipjakk's answer. [Strange Behavior of Stepper in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960251/strange-behavior-of-stepper-in-swiftui)

Comment: This does not solve your problem. You decided to use a different approach without the slider.